discord.py inputmodal keep failing and saying "Something went wrong, please try again"
discord.py inputmodal keep failing and saying "Something went wrong, please try again". whats wrong with this code??
class InputModal(Modal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(title="Input HWID")
        self.add_item(TextInput(label="Enter your HWID"))

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        user_input = self.children[0].value
        print(user_input)
        user_id = interaction.user.id
        user_name = str(interaction.user)
        # ㄱclass MyView(View):
    @discord.ui.button(label="Add HWID", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def add_entry(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: Button):
        print('da')
        await interaction.response.send_modal(InputModal())

class MyView(View):
    @discord.ui.button(label="Add HWID", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def add_entry(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: Button):
        print('da')
        await interaction.response.send_modal(InputModal())

i tried debugging and i even asked chatgpt and find no solution.

There was an API outage last night, should be working now. Next time please monitor https://discordstatus.com/
